# Passenger, RoR + Apache Bundler:Gemnotfound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, deployment, rubygems, passenger

I'm trying to set up my own VPS (Ubuntu 14.04), and have almost succeeded (I hope!).

I'm using passenger, Rails and Apache. When I browse to my IP, I get a bundle GemError, though when I run bundle install on my machine it tells me it's using all gems.

The problem first occurred with the json gem, which is the first gem. When I manually added "gem json, 1.8.3" to my Gemfile, the error went to the second gem of the list, minitest.

There are two weird messages on top which might be the problem, but I do not really understand those messages:

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7



Could not find minitest-5.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:399:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:277:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:404:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:276:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:99:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Passenger author here. This error usually means one of two things:

1. Your app isn't being run as the user that it's supposed to be run as. Please set `passenger_user` to explicitly specify a user.
2. Your app isn't being run with the Ruby interpreter that it's supposed to be run as. Please set `passenger_ruby` to explicitly set a path to the Ruby interpreter that is supposed to be used.

If all fails, try our [new end-to-end deployment walkthrough](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/). It should work guaranteed (assuming you are starting from scratch and using the latest Passenger version).